# Div bind/live activating all methods

Tags: bind, jquery

I have some divs being created dynamically and I'm using bind/live (tried both, same results) to add a click function. However, it is returning all the divs with the same class.

Example;

I have 3 dynamically generated divs

1
2
3

If I click on 2, the alert method goes to show 1 then 2 then 3. I only need the one clicked. Thanks!

```
$("#borang_main_form").append('<div class="borang-row" id="'+id+'"><label id="label_'+id+'"></label><input id="textbox_'+id+'" type="text" /></div>').bind("click", function(){alert(id);});
```

I've tried this and it works.

```
$("#borang_main_form").append('<div class="borang-row" id="'+id+'"><label id="label_'+id+'"></label><input id="textbox_'+id+'" type="text" /></div>').delegate("#" + id, "click", function(){alert(id);});
```

However it looks a little dirty. Is there a better way to approach something like this?

Comment: Show us your attempt please

Comment: @JanDvorak Thanks, I've added the code as per your request. Could you please show me how I could improve it? Btw id is a randomly generated integer. It's not undefined.

Comment: Maybe I gave my answer prematurely. From the looks of it, you're appending dynamic html and then calling .bind() directly after it. If you aren't aware, jquery chaining is returning the actual `#borang_main_form` object itself, and binding that. It's not binding the individual html elements with click events.

Comment: @FarisM Thanks a lot! I apologize if my question wasn't clear but it just only clicked as to why it was behaving that way. You made perfect sense. .delegate works right now. Is it the right way of approaching it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate with your loop, you use method chaining, which basically end up adding n number of event bindings to the same parent item ("#borang_main_form")

In your loop first append the items, then outside the loop add the event listeners to the individual children elements.

```
for(var i=0; i<3; i++)
{
  var id = i;
  $("#borang_main_form").append('<div class="borang-row" id="'+id+'"><label id="label_'+id+'"></label><input id="textbox_'+id+'" type="text" /></div>')
}
$('.borang-row').on("click", function(){alert($(this).attr('id'));});
```

In the event handler function $(this) will be mapped as the item that was clicked (the trigger of the event) and through `$(this).attr('id')` you will get the id attribute of that element.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I can now honestly say I understand why it was working in that way.

Comment: Great, I am glad to help. If you feel that I answered your question, would you mind accepting it please? Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(e.target)` in your click handler `function(e){ ... }` to get a jquery object referencing the element you actually clicked on.

http://jsfiddle.net/fDZ4J/1/